# Dropbox API (Python) - file revision and user name

Tags: api, dropbox, revisions

I'm using the Dropbox API (for Python) to list files in a shared folder.

Just as proposed by the "Version history" option on Dropbox website, is it possible to know if any of these file has been modified or deleted **by an other user** than me (with whom I shared the folder) with the API, and get his user name ?

The informations provided by the `DropboxClient.revisions()` function do not tell which user is responsible of the modification...

Answer (score 0):

There are no supported ways for doing this. If you have both users Auth'd you could do comparisons. Otherwise, you don't have both users Auth'd and another user's edits are beyond the permissions.